# Angular Share service subject binding problem

Tags: angular, typescript

I created shared service with Subject:

```
  totalCostSource$ = new Subject<number>();

  shareCost(cost: number ) {
    this.totalCostSource$.next(cost);
  }
```

and in my component I have

```
  private incomeTax: number = 18;
  income: number;

  constructor(private costService: CostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.costSubsription = this.costService.totalCostSource$.subscribe( cost => {
      this.income = cost * this.incomeTax / 100;
      console.log(this.income); // return proper value
    });
  }
```

And I have problem with binding income in my view.
In console value is correct but view is not refreshing.
How can I fix it?

Comment: hi mate, how do u bind in your html? You assign a number to an object. You should try changing the type of income to number.

Comment: sorry, I edit my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maciek77
I am not sure what's the reason, because it's hard to tell anything without template, component which calls `shareCost`.

Please check:

- `shareCost` is called after `totalCostSource$.subscribe`
- If you use `onPush` or your change detector is detached, detect changes manually
- `subscribe` actually returns proper value of type `number`

If that does not help, please share:

- HTML Template where `income` is used
- Typescript code whole components (both calling `shareCost` and `subject.subscribe`

Comment: subscribe return proper value in console.log

Comment: But where? Please share what I have requested or contact me with email, we are from the same country so I think I can help you. e-mail is in my about me page

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.costSubsription = this.costService.totalCostSource$.subscribe( cost => {
      this.income = cost * this.incomeTax / 100;
      console.log(this.income); // return proper value
    });
  }

Comment: What about template? Do you use `onPush?`

Comment: Template is easy: INCOME TAX: {{ income }} and I don't use onPush.

Comment: I really can't help you without your code. You gave me just a little piece of your code, and that's not enough.